# jenkins_plugin failing with "Connection timed out" error

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am using ansible [jenkins_plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_plugin_module.html) module to install jenkins plugin it intermittently fails with this error

```
failed: [custom-jenkins] (item={u'name': u'artifactory'}) => {"details": "Connection failure: timed out", "failed": true, "item": {"name": "artifactory"}, "msg": "Cannot install plugin."}
```

So far I have tried with multiple ansible versions(2.6, 2.7, 2.9.2)  and they all run with same error.

Here is the source code I am using(referenced from geerlingy github source):

```
- name: Install plugins with a specific version and restart jenkins
  jenkins_plugin:
    name: "{{ item.name | default(item) }}"
    version: "{{ item.version | default(omit) }}"
    state: "{{ 'present' if item.version is defined else jenkins_plugins_state }}"
    timeout: "{{ jenkins_plugin_timeout }}"
    updates_expiration: "{{ jenkins_plugin_updates_expiration }}"
    updates_url: "{{ jenkins_updates_url }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ jenkins_plugins }}"
  notify: restart jenkins
  tags: plugins
  register: plugin_result
  until: plugin_result is success
  retries: 5
  delay: 8

jenkins_plugins:
  - name: ant
  - name: artifactory
```

There was a similar [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19829) it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you able to connect to `{{ jenkins_updates_url }}` manually ? is there any firewall or proxy settings configured ?

Comment: Please check I have mentioned issue is intermittent

Answer (score 0):

I think too many retries were not helping as well. Intermittent Connection timed out is still there but reducing the retries at least fixed the issue.

```
 retries: 2
 delay: 3
```